# How to configure external postgresql database in chef automate server

Tags: postgresql, configuration, chef-infra

I want to know how can we configure chef automate server to use external postgresql database. I have one chef server which is configured with external elasticsearch and postgresql database, now i want to use that same postgresql database in chef automate server. Can somebody tell me how can i achieve that?

Here is my delivery.rb file configuration

```
 delivery_fqdn "192.168.0.101"
 delivery['chef_username'] = "delivery"
 delivery['chef_private_key'] = "/etc/delivery/delivery.pem"
 delivery['chef_server'] = "https://192.168.0.102/organizations/automate_org"
 insights['enable'] = true
 elasticsearch['urls'] = ['http://192.168.0.103:9200']
 elasticsearch['external'] = true
 data_collector['token'] = 'helloworld123'
 postgresql['version'] = '9.6'
 postgresql['external'] = true
 postgresql['vip'] = '192.168.0.103'
 postgresql['port'] = '5432'
 postgresql['username'] = 'admin'
 postgresql['superuser_username'] = 'admin'
 postgresql['superuser_password'] = 'admin123'
```

Here is my chef-server.rb

```
postgresql['external'] = true
postgresql['vip'] = '192.168.0.103'
postgresql['port'] = 5432
postgresql['db_superuser'] = 'admin'
postgresql['db_superuser_password'] = 'admin123'
opscode_erchef['search_provider'] = 'elasticsearch'
opscode_solr4['external'] = true
opscode_solr4['external_url'] = 'http://192.168.0.103:9200'
opscode_solr4['elasticsearch_shard_count'] = 3
opscode_solr4['elasticsearch_replica_count'] = 2
opscode_erchef['search_queue_mode'] = 'batch'
rabbitmq['enable'] = false
rabbitmq['management_enabled'] = false
rabbitmq['queue_length_monitor_enabled'] = false
opscode_expander['enable'] = false
dark_launch['actions'] = false
data_collector['root_url'] = 'https://192.168.0.101/data-collector/v0'
profiles['root_url'] = 'https://192.168.0.101'
```

Answer (score 0):

Chef Automate server still uses Chef Server, [see Automate setup here](https://docs.chef.io/install_chef_automate.html). `delivery.rb` is for [Automate](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_delivery.html) settings that are non-defaults. The Chef Server settings likely still need set in `chef-server.rb`, [see here](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_server_optional_settings.html), then run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` since Automate still stores cookbooks and data in Chef Server.

Comment: I saw above configuration files but the problem is i don't want to use postgresql database that ships with chef automate server which is installed locally. i want to use postgresql database in chef automate server which is installed on another instance. Using above configuration i am unable to achieve that functionality. How can i achieve that?

Comment: You mentioned you have another Chef Server woth this configured, what does it's `chef-server.rb` file look like? your automate server should be set up with a similar `chef-server.rb` file. `delivery.rb` is just for automate settings.